# ThreeJS access objects within loaded obj model

Tags: javascript, three.js

Say I have a obj model of a map consisted of tree objects, and I can load the model successfully, how can I access one tree object called Tree1?

Currently I have

```js
loader.load( 'map.obj', function ( object ) {
     scene.add( object );
     var Tree1 = object.getObjectByName( "Tree1" );
     console.log(Tree1.position.x + " " + Tree1.position.y + " " + Tree1.position.z);

     
    }, onProgress, onError );
```

It always give me (0,0,0) no matter which object I choose.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `Tree1` really contains your mesh. Then call:

`console.log( Tree1.getWorldPosition() );`

to get its "absolute" position.